# Dart Generic type not inferred correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

In the code below, I am expecting an error at  `await postApi(payload, api);` because payload should be an instance of `Foo` not `String` but Dart does not complain. The class`MyRequest` is shared between backend and frontend to avoid bug but if the compiler doesn't complain, it is useless. How can make this work ?  (could be (yet) another bug in Dart yes, but is there a workaround or tweak to make it work ?)

```
typedef JsonMap = Map<String, dynamic>;

enum ApiRoutes {
  nextDuel,
}

abstract class BaseRequestResponse<I, O> {
  ApiRoutes get api;
  I fromJsonReq(JsonMap json);
  JsonMap toJsonRes(O model);
  O fromJsonRes(JsonMap json);
  JsonMap toJsonReq(I model);
}


class Foo {}

class Bar {}

class MyRequest extends BaseRequestResponse<Foo, Bar> {
  @override
  ApiRoutes get api => ApiRoutes.nextDuel;

  @override
  Foo fromJsonReq(JsonMap json) {
    return Foo();
  }

  @override
  Bar fromJsonRes(JsonMap json) {
    return Bar();
  }

  @override
  JsonMap toJsonReq(Foo model) {
    return {};
  }

  @override
  JsonMap toJsonRes(Bar model) {
    return {};
  }
}

Future<O> postApi<I, O>(I payload, BaseRequestResponse<I, O> api) async {
  return api.fromJsonRes({});
}

void main() {
  callApi();
}

Future<Bar> callApi() async {
  final String payload = 'wrong';
  final api = MyRequest();
  final data = await postApi(payload, api);
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `postApi` with two different candidate types for `I` (`String` and `Foo`), `I` is inferred to be their nearest common base type, which is `Object`.  Therefore your `postApi` call is inferred to be `postApi<Object, Bar>`. That's a valid inference, although it's not what you wanted. (You can verify that this is what's happening by adding `print('I: $I, O: $O')` to the body of `postApi`.)

If you don't want to have to explicitly specify type arguments at every call site, one way to constrain `postApi` would be to break up the call so that `I` must be determined first from only one argument.  For example:

```dart
class PostApi<I, O> {
  final BaseRequestResponse<I, O> api;

  PostApi(this.api);

  Future<O> apply(I payload) async {
    return api.fromJsonRes({});
  }
}

Future<Bar> callApi() async {
  final String payload = 'wrong';
  final api = MyRequest();
  final data = await PostApi(api).apply(payload);
  return data;
}
```

which generates an error message:

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Foo'.

but works when `payload` is an instance of `Foo`.

Comment: Yeah this is similar to what I ended up doing, I passed the payload in the request instead like so `final api = MyRequest(payload);`  +1 for the explanation about nearest common base